# How to perform a certain action in the application by the google assistant

Tags: android, app-actions

How to perform a certain action in the app by the google assistant

Hello, I have an alarm app that lists all registered devices (gate, electric fence, etc.) and I have implemented the alarm/disarm feature of one alarm per device. Is it possible to create a custom internal intent for from a voice command with static shortcut using google assistant "ok google, alarm xpto device in test app" i enable or disable a device in my app to perform this action by opening the app manually in pt-br language?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.